# How to maintain case-Sensitive key in Python Click options

Tags: python, click, python-click

I am using Python Click to generate a json file. However, I need to maintain the case-sensitivity of keys. Python Click converts all keys into lower case implicitly and hence my generated json has lower case keys, not the one I like.

Example code is below

```
@click.option('--tempId', default=None, help='tempId')
```

In the above example, tempId is converted into tempid. Is there way to handle this? I am aware that values can be converted to lower or upper, but my requirement is to main the Key case as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```py
@cli.command('test')
@click.option('--tempId', '--tempId', 'tempId', default=None, help='tempId')
def test(tempId):
    print(tempId)
```

where if I invoke it with `--tempId` it finds the key, but if I invoke it with `--tempid` it doesn't.

Comment: Where is this behaviour documented?

Comment: Found it, sort of: ["If a name is not prefixed, it is used as the Python argument name and not treated as an option name on the command line."](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/options/). This is still ambiguous since the following line says "To get the Python argument name, the chosen name is converted to lower case, up to two dashes are removed as the prefix, and other dashes are converted to underscores", but it seems from [this update](https://github.com/pallets/click/pull/1016/files) that keeping the non-prefixed name is the intended behaviour.